# Linear combination of functions that is closest to a certain function in a non-trivial norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Consider the vector space $C([0,1])$ of continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$ mapped to $\mathbb{C}$. Define the norm as $$ ||f|| = \left( \int^1_0x|f(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}.$$ What combination of the functions $F:x \mapsto 1$ and $G:x \mapsto x$ lies as close as possible to the function $H:x \mapsto x^2$?

I started by defining $K=\text{span} \{F,G\}$ and noticing that $H$ can be written as a sum of an element from $K$ and an element from the orthogonal set of $K$. I also think I have to use the orthogonal projection. But I can't see how to go further.

Comment: As defined, $\|\cdot\|$ is not a norm. Maybe you have to change an exponent $2$ and make it a square root

Comment: @Albert yes my bad, the exponent has to be 1/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you meant
$$
\|f\| = \left( \int_0^1 x |f(x)|^2 \; dx\right)^{1/2}.
$$
The bilinear form on $C([0,1])$ defined by
$$
(f,g) = \int_0^1 x f(x)g(x) \; dx
$$
is an inner product on $C([0,1])$ inducing the norm $\|\cdot\|$. Using Gram-Schmidt process, you find that the set $\{u,v\}$ where $u:x\mapsto \sqrt{2}$ and $v:x\mapsto 6x-4$ is an orthonormal basis of $K=\operatorname{span}(F,G)$. Then we can use the projetion formula to compute
$$
w = \operatorname{proj}_K(H) = (H,u)u + (H,v)v = \frac{5x}{6} - \frac{3}{10},
$$
and thus $w$ is the element in $K$ closest to $H$.

(Sorry if I made a calculation mistake, but I hope the general idea is clear).

Comment: how are $u$ and $v$ an orthonormal basis?

Comment: @Geigercounter because with the inner product I just defined you have $(u,v)=\int_0^1 x\cdot \sqrt{2}\cdot (6x-4) \; dx = 0$ so $\{u,v\}$ is orthogonal, and if you compute their norms with your definition, then they have norm $1$.